# server stuck at the boot process:RECEIVED SIGTERM

Tags: boot, ping, sigterm

The issue is when I try to log in the server using SSh , it's not responding and cannot be pinged. And when I go to the console and reboot the server, its stuck in the reboot process. How Can this issue be resolved.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the server crashes when you try to login with ssh?

Comment: No, there is no response when I try to log in using ssh. And when I reboot the server in VSphere console, it gets stuck in the server reboot.

Comment: :-O , im sorry i still cannot understand your question, maybe because my english is very bad.   Are you saying that the system is not booting properly or stopping at the boot? Or it is just broken only in the reboot?, but it can boot if you do that manually?

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains too little information to provide any good tip. It looks like it is a systemd based linux derivate that fails to switch onto the root partition during the boot process. Which seems to cause that systemd stops (SIGTERM) the systemd-jourald which is taking care of journal logs.

At this point during the boot process, networking is not even setup, so you can forget any attempt to connect via ssh or any other network protocol. The machine does not even have an ip assigned.

Answer (score 0):

This might help to find the issue:

OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 38: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "server" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server[server] port 22.
debug1: connect to address server port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host server port 22: Connection timed out